# how to compile binaries in linux which can be run without preceding ./

Tags: c, linux, gcc

When I compile a program using gcc it should be run using prepending ./ e.g. 
gcc -Wall -o hello-world hello-world.c
will produce binary hello-world which i have to run it as ./hello-world But I want to run it as any other system bimary just by typing hellow-world how to compile it ?

Comment: No tricks, the executable either (1) has to be in your `$PATH` or (2) you must precede the executable name with `./` (or an absolute path). It has nothing to do with "how you compile it" (of course you do have to compile it...).

Answer (score 2):

As a note to the answers of @BraveNewCurrency and @songziming to place the executable in the search path.

It is possible to execute the executable without adding the `./`. To do that you have to add the current directory to the search path. Like this:
 `export PATH='./:'$PATH`

This is however generally frowned upon because it can have some unintended side effects. Some people even regard it as a safety risk.
See for instance https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default

Comment: Thanks to all answers. adding path to my current directory has solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the directory containing executable to `$PATH` to run it without `./`. It has nothing to do with compilation.

Say file `hello-world` is located in `/root/hello`, you have to add it to `PATH` like: `export PATH=$PATH:/root/hello`, then you can run it with `hello-world`.

Linux bash commands are just executable files, you can tell the location using `which`:

```
$ which ps
/bin/ps
```

When you type a command without `./`, bash searches all directories listed in `PATH` environment variable to see if it contains the executable you typed, and run it when found. On my machine, the content of `PATH` is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/bochs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/node-v5.1.1-linux-x64/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_65/bin:/opt/neovim/bin:/sbin:/opt/node-v5.1.1-linux-x64/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_65/bin
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing very much as `root`; it should be in `$HOME/bin`, probably.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with how it's compiled. Linux only runs things that are in your `$PATH`. So you can copy the binary to /bin, /usr/bin, and sometimes /usr/local/bin. You can also add ~/bin to your path and put the binary there.